# Akka Stream : dynamically grow outlets during graph builder phase

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I understand in Akka Stream one outlet must be connected to one inlet and there is no automatic support for connecting multiple sinks to the same source. So you have to insert intermediate objects such as `Broadcast`.

I am transforming a signal processing DAG into a Akka Stream graph, and it would help me a lot if I could dynamically add sinks to sources as they are discovered on the traversal. If I have a custom `GraphStage`, can I have my own `Shape` whose `outlets` collection grows dynamically during the `Graph.create` phase? The normal DSL operation `~>` is backed by this call:

```
b.addEdge(importAndGetPort(b), to)
```

How does the builder "get" the `Outlet` here and would I be able to grow my shape on demand?

---

If this does not work, is it possible to "eject" a previous broadcast, disconnect its edges and wire them up with a new larger broadcast during the graph building?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the underlying question but this design has one big drawback: the source would broadcast values only as fast as the slowest destination.  The broadcast only signals more demand when all sinks have processed a message.  Your problem seems much better suited to using Actors directly.  You could then use routing to dynamically added destinations to an Actor.  http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/routing.html

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil yes, source can only process once all sinks are ready. This is intentional, because source node might perform expensive and non-repeatable computation. If needed, I can insert buffers between source and sink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GraphDSL does not allow to mutate your shape dynamically.

However, since Akka 2.4.10 you can use BroadcastHub (and MergeHub).

BroadcastHub can give you a Sink that materializes into a Source.
This Source can in turn be materialized as many times as needed to dynamically attach multiple subscribers.

So for a node of your DAG (e.g. having indegree=1 and outdegree=3), you could have something like

```
val hubSource = inEdgeSource.toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = ...))(Keep.right).run()

val nodeSink1 = hubSource.to(outEdgeSink1).run()
val nodeSink2 = hubSource.to(outEdgeSink2).run()
val nodeSink3 = hubSource.to(outEdgeSink3).run()
```

Akka docs:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html#Dynamic_fan-in_and_fan-out_with_MergeHub_and_BroadcastHub